# How can I draw a Hasse Diagram divisibility?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

We just started learning graphs and I wanted to know how can I draw the Hasse diagram for divisibility on the sets:

1. {$6, 10, 14, 15, 21, 22, 26, 33, 35, 39, 55, 65, 77, 91, 143$}

In class we worked with much smaller sets and smaller numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those numbers divide any other number. The Hasse diagram is just a bunch of isolated points.

Comment: thanks, That is what I thought but I just wanted to make sure it was correct

Comment: can I ask you another question?

Comment: {$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$} which two numbers are incomparable?

Comment: @Csci319 Incomparable as in $a$ doesn't divide $b$ and $b$ doesn't divide $a$? $(5,3)$ and $(4,6)$  examples of are such pairs. By the transitivity of divisibility it suffices to show that the two numbers are mutually non-divissible.

Comment: thanks so much.
do you think you can take a look at my other question and perhaps help me? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253610/determining-which-graphs-are-bitpartite-2-colorable-and-which-are-not

Comment: Sadly, no. I don't know anything about graph theory. I just happened to know about Hasse diagrams from other books.